# Javascript dynamically change image

Tags: javascript

I'm actually not even sure where to start with this due to being stomped with the fact that my check-boxes already have a function to calculate their prices.

Basically, I need to dynamically update the image on a pizza base so every-time a topping is selected (check boxes) the image for topping selected will appear on the base image already on the page.

In my html for the base I have:

```
<div class="base">
            <img id="pBase" alt= "Pizza " src="img/base.png" />
</div>
```

For my checkboxes I have something like:

```
input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="topping1" onclick="Total()" /> Topping1<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="topping2" onclick="Total()" /> Topping2<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="topping3" onclick="Total()" /> Topping3<br />
```

Now currently, my function Total() is to dynamically update the prices as each topping is selected and it's working grand.

So where do I start in terms of creating another function to dynamically build the pizza with the topping images being selected or I have still use function Total()? if so how do I proceed?

```
var top_type = new Array();
top_type["topping1"]=2.00;
top_type["topping2"]=2.00;
top_type["topping3"]=2.00;

function getTopPrice()
{
    var TopPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["orderform"];
    var topOption = theForm.elements["topping"];
    for(var i = 0; i < topOption.length; i++)
    {
        if(topOption[i].checked==true)
        {
            TopPrice += top_type[topOption[i].value];
        }
    }
    return TopPrice;
```

Hopefully this question makes sense as it isn't in my head/

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: Will get to this once I get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple approach:
To start, lay out an array of images that map to your toppings.  You can do this similar to your prices.

```
var top_img = new Array();
top_img["topping1"]="topping1.jpg";
top_img["topping2"]="topping2.jpg";
top_img["topping3"]="topping3.jpg";
```

While you are looping through the prices, and you find a checked item, just grab the image then and show it (inside your existing if statement).

You'll have to do a quick read up on opacity to overlay the images.

Piece of cake!  (or pizza)

You could also refactor this to not use a loop in either case, but I didn't want to completely refactor your work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you bind a click event by using onclick attribute; so, just to get this working you sure may use your Total() function (I can't see that func in your listing, tho). 
You can make a transparent image for every topping having the id that equals the value of the proper topping checkbox and toggle its visibility.